# Copy SVN log messages when merging using 'svn merge'

Tags: windows, svn, merge, continuous-integration, message

When merging changes from one branch to another, it is tedious to look up the changes in the log for the relevant ranges and manually copy the messages. TortoiseSVN does solve this pretty well through the "Recent messages" button, but I had to solve this through 'svn merge' for a continuous integration setup.

I thought this was a common issue, but could not find any solutions out there so here is my own. Please feel free to post better solutions as answers to this.

### My Scenario

I periodically want to merge 1:HEAD from /trunk to /branches/AutoDeploy. AutoDeploy will never be committed on except for the merges, so that should simplify things.
I want to merge using 'svn merge' or similar command line tool and I want the commit message to include all messages from the merged revisions.

The solution must work for SVN and on Windows, but bonus points for being compatible with other operating systems.

Edit: Split up question and answer.

Comment: It's better to restructure this question into a question and an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### My Solution

To trigger a deployment through continuous integration I run a batch script that merges the latest changes from trunk, retrieves the relevant log messages and commits with those messages.

The script goes something like this:

- Get revision of branch using svnversion and sed.exe + regex.
- Get log messages of trunk from branch revision to HEAD, save to messages.txt.
- Merge trunk into branch.
- Commit with --file messages.txt.

---

**Folder structure**

```
/trunk
/branches/AutoDeploy
/branches/AutoDeploy/AutoDeployTools
/branches/AutoDeploy/AutoDeployTools/Merge_from_trunk.bat
/branches/AutoDeploy/AutoDeployTools/sed.exe
/branches/AutoDeploy/AutoDeployTools/current_rev.txt*
/branches/AutoDeploy/AutoDeployTools/messages.txt*
```

* Temporary files generated for each merge.

**Merge_from_trunk.bat**

```
@echo off

del *.txt
SET MessagesFile=messages.txt
SET CurrentRevFile=current_rev.txt
SET RepoUrl=svn://<host>
SET LocalBranchPath=../

REM CD %LocalBranchPath%

REM Get current revision for branch. Typically formatted as "683:684".
echo|set /p=Getting current revision for branch...
svnversion -c -n %LocalBranchPath% /branches/AutoDeployWeb > %CurrentRevFile%

REM Strip away number before colon (683:684 => 684)
sed -i s/.*\:// %CurrentRevFile%

REM Strip away any characters that indicate Modified (M), Switched (S) etc.
sed -i s/[a-zA-Z]// %CurrentRevFile%

SET /p BranchRev=<%CurrentRevFile%
echo DONE! 
echo Current revision in AutoDeployWeb is %BranchRev%.

REM Retrieve relevant log messages for this merge.
echo|set /p=Getting log messages for revisions %BranchRev%:HEAD...
svn log %RepoUrl%/trunk -r %BranchRev%:HEAD > %MessagesFile%
echo DONE!

REM Merge
echo Merging...
svn up %LocalBranchPath%
svn merge svn://dev.swingcatalyst.com/SC_Online/trunk %LocalBranchPath%
echo Merging DONE!

REM Commit
echo|set /p=Committing...
echo Commit message:
type %MessagesFile%
svn commit --file %MessagesFile% %LocalBranchPath%
echo DONE!
pause
```

**Known Limitations**

- The current implementation does not allow you to add text to the commit message, but that should be trivial to add.
- If the branch is committed to, ouside of merging, it cause svnversion to not include log messages from revisions before the last branch commit. There are solutions for this, such as parsing the svn merge text output instead of using svnversion.

Edit: Added another known limitation.
Edit: Added sed.exe to folder structure.